# Why aren't CPU instructions decoded before the program runs?

Tags: memory, cpu, 64-bit, cpu-architecture, x86

What is it about the decoding step of the instruction cycle that prevents it from being done ahead of time?

The Intel 64 manual says things like "decodes instructions into micro-operations".

Ulrich Drepper in *What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory* said:

> Getting data into the cache as soon as possible is even more important
> for the instruction cache. As mentioned in section 3.1, instructions
> have to be decoded before they can be executed and, to speed this up
> (important on x86 and x86-64), instructions are actually cached in the
> decoded form, not in the byte/word form read from memory.

It seems like if it were possible to store this "decoded form" in main memory before the program ran, it would be stored there. What is it about this decoded form that prevents it from being computed and stored ahead of time?

Comment: A decoded instruction would surely require much more bits to store than the original machine instruction.  It would also be less "secure", that is any corruption or bad value could perform invalid micro-operations.  Besides RISC is already a major step to simplify machine instruction decoding compared to CISC.

Comment: @sawdust So in addition to leaving room for better implementations of the ISA, backwards compatibility, and protecting CPU-makers' trade secrets, decoders also provide micro-operation validation and instruction decompression (enabling instruction compression, which reduces instruction cache misses by allowing more instructions to be in cache).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the x86-64 instruction set is well defined and allows backwards compatibility. Using the core instruction set would mean that programs would need to be recompiled for every new CPU generation, or CPU generations would be required to be fully backwards compatible.

In modern x86 CPUs actual execution core of the CPU works differently to the instructions as defined by the x86 instruction set, and this decode step gives them scope to change the core architecture without making breaking changes to the external architecture.

AMD and Intel cores have a common external x86-64 architecture, but the decode stage means that the internal cores can be substantially different and work in similar but functionally different ways to achieve the same goal.

It also means that minor improvements can be made to the underlying cores, giving us generational speed improvements, without needing to change the programs themselves to take advantage of them. Sure there are new instructions every now and then, but these are fundamentally new ways of executing a stream of instructions, not making existing instructions more effective.

Comment: Would it be correct to say?: x86-64 instructions are like high level language statements, and the decoder is like a compiler for that high level language. Perhaps allowing programmers to bypass the decoding step by letting them provide microarchitecture-specific micro-code would mess up the hardware component layout; and even if it didn't, it would require the CPU-maker to release their decoder as software which could reveal some of their trade secrets.

Comment: Essentially yes. The architecture is now essentially a fast and agile RISC CPU core surrounded by an "old school" CISC frontend with associated hardware decoder. Nvidias [Project Denver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Denver) was originally meant to be a CPU core with a frontend that could be swapped between x86 and ARM but due to licencing issues x86 was dropped.